# Is there a way to change multiple lines depending on a condition?

Tags: ifthenelse

I'm working on my resume, and I have two versions -- one more tailored towards the Biology/premed side of my experience, and another focused more on my computational side. Right now, whenever I'm updating my resume, I have to comment/uncomment each section that differs between the two. I'm curious if there's a way to set a variable/condition at the start of my document (e.g. mode = Bio, or Bio = true), and then have each of the other lines render depending on that condition. I'm using Overleaf at the moment, and tried this:

```
\def\bio{T}
      \ifx\bio\T
        bio stuff here
      \else
        cs stuff here
```

But I get this:

```
    l.125       \if\bio\T
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any help/advice? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You defined `\bio` with `{T}`.  Wny would you want to check it as a "control sequence", `\T`?  Try `\ifx\bio{T}`.

Comment: The [multiaudience](https://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience?lang=en) package looks to be exactly what you want. If it is, let me know, and I will write up a full answer.